# Longest substring where every character appear even number of times (possibly zero)

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

> Suppose we have a string `s`. We want to find the length of the longest substring of `s` such that every character in the substring appears even number of times (possible zero).
>   WC Time: `O(nlgn)`. WC space: `O(n)`

First, it's obvious that the substring must be of an even length. Second, I'm familiar with the sliding window method where we anchor some `right` index and look for the left-most index to match your criterion. I tried to apply this idea here but couldn't really formulate it.

Also, it seems to me like a priority queue could come in handy (since the `O(nlgn)` requirement is sort of hinting it)

I'd be glad for help!

Comment: When you say "substring", do you mean a continuous substring, or can characters be left out (i.e. a subsequence)?

Comment: Yes, a continuous substring (not a subsequence)

Comment: Thought so, the other would be pretty trivial. Still wanted to clarify.

Comment: Is the alphabet size considered constant?

Comment: @amit, yes, for simplicity we can even assume only `a-z` characters may appear (actually it just crossed my mind too and might be helpful)

Comment: @Elimination I think in this case that can be done in O(n) time.. let me formulate a solution and see if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's define the following bitsets:

```
B[c,i] = 1 if character c appeared in s[0,...,i] even number of times.
```

Calculating `B[c,i]` takes linear time (for all values):

```
for all c:
  B[c,-1] = 0
for i from 0 to len(arr):
  B[c, i] = B[s[i], i-1] XOR 1
```

Since the alphabet is of constant size, so are the bitsets (for each `i`).

Note that the condition:

> every character in the substring appears even number of times

is true for substring `s[i,j]` if and only if the bitset of index `i` is identical to the bitset of index `j` (otherwise, there is a bit that repeated odd number of times in this substring ; other direction: If there is a bit that repeated number of times, then its bit cannot be identical).

So, if we store all bitsets in some set (hash set/tree set), and keep only latest entry, this preprocessing takes `O(n)` or `O(nlogn)` time (depending on hash/tree set).

In a second iteration, for each index, find the farther away index with identical bitset (`O(1)/O(logn)`, depending if hash/tree set), find the substring length, and mark it as candidate. At the end, take the longest candidate.

This solution is `O(n)` space for the bitsets, and `O(n)/O(nlogn)` time, depending if using hash/tree solution.

---

Pseudo code:

```
def NextBitset(B, c): # O(1) time
  for each x in alphabet \ {c}:
    B[x, i] = B[x, i-1]
   B[c, i] = B[c, i-1] XOR 1

for each c in alphabet: # O(1) time
  B[c,-1] = 0
map = new hash/tree map (bitset->int)

# first pass: # O(n)/O(nlogn) time
for i from 0 to len(s):
   # Note, we override with the latest element.
   B = NextBitset(B, s[i])
   map[B] = i

for each c in alphabet: # O(1) time
  B[c,-1] = 0
max_distance = 0
# second pass: O(n)/ O(nlogn) time.
for i from 0 to len(s):
  B = NextBitset(B, s[i])
  j = map.find(B)  # O(1) / O(logn)
  max_distance = max(max_distance, j-i)
```

Comment: Thank you amit! so for the "second iteration", I would do some sort of a binary search? (Otherwise it would take `O(n^2)`)

Comment: Oh never mind, you mentioned that one comparison would take `O(1)/O(lgn)`, since it's a bitset.

Comment: @Elimination The important thing is it's a bitset with **constant size** :)

Comment: Wait a sec, something isn't right: if you do the second phase for every index you'd end up with `O(n^2)`. How did you get a linear time? (suppose constant time for comparing two bitsets)

Comment: @Elimination In the second phase, for every index you just do a map lookup, which is O(1)/O(logn), I'll add a pseudo code to clarify.

Comment: Okay, I missed that. Thank you for the elaboration!

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure exactly what amit proposes so if this is it, please consider it another explanation. This can be accomplished in a single traversal.

Produce a bitset of length equal to the alphabet's for each index of the string. Store the first index for each unique bitset encountered while traversing the string. Update the largest interval between a current and previously seen bitset.

For example, the string, "aabccab":

```
  a a b c c a b
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 (index)

                _
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1  |  (vertical)
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0  |  bitset for
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 _|  each index
  ^           ^
  |___________|

   largest interval
   between current and
   previously seen bitset
```

The update for each iteration can be accomplished in O(1) by preprocessing a bit mask for each character to `XOR` with the previous bitset:

```
bitset     mask
  0         1     1
  1   XOR   0  =  1
  0         0     0
```

means update the character associated with the first bit in the alphabet-bitset.